# Create new outlook exchange server email in python with win32com

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, pywin32

'Application.CreateItemFromTemplate' and 'Application.CreateItem()' don't work. I believe it has something to do with the fact that I'm running Outlook Exchange Office 365 instead of the standard outlook session.

I am able to find emails in my mailbox and open them, but I am not able to find a way to create a new email.

my code:

```
import win32com.client

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace('MAPI')
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
sentbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5)
all_sentbox = sentbox.Items
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders
tryopen = outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(r'Documents\a.oft')
```

error:

```
tryopen = outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(r'Documents\a.oft')
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.CreateItemFromTemplate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to specify the absolute file path when calling `CreateItemFromTemplate` - Outlook is an out-of-proc COM library running in the outlook.exe address space, so its current folder is different from that of your app.

Secondly, `CreateItemFromTemplate` is exposed by the `Application` object, not `Namespace`. You need to store `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")` in a separate variable rather than using it as an implicit variable to call `Application.GetNameSpace('MAPI')`.

Naming your variables to reflect their type would also be a good idea - `outlook` probably can better called `namespace` or `ns`, while return value of the `Dispatch("Outlook.Application")` call can be named `application` or `app`.

Comment: It's still giving the same error.

Comment: See the updated answer above.